# How to create map with different type in pyspark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having a requirement where i have to concat map of different types.

Sample data will be of :

```
+----------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+----+----+

|ADDRESS_ID|              CAS_ID|VERSION|RG_ADDRESS|IS_VERIFIED|GEOFENCE_RADIUS|ADDRESS_RECENCY|ADDRESS_SCORE| LAT| LNG|

+----------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+----+----+

|  75199688|tmdsfggds|6|          |      false|           1000|              1|           85|null|null|
```

I have tried below but its not workinf duee to type mismatch:

```
column_list_string = ['ADDRESS_ID', 'CAS_ID','RG_ADDRESS']
column_list_int = ['VERSION', 'GEOFENCE_RADIUS', 'ADDRESS_RECENCY', 'ADDRESS_SCORE']
column_list_double = ['LAT', 'LNG']
column_list_bool = ['IS_VERIFIED']

def convert(s, c = column_list):
    print(s,c)
    return {c[0]: s[0], c[1] : s[1], c[2]: s[2], c[3]: s[3], c[4] : s[4], c[5]: s[5] ,c[6]: s[6], c[7] : s[7], c[8]: s[8] ,c[9]: s[9]}
    
convert_udf_str = F.udf(convert, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
convert_udf_int = F.udf(convert, MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
convert_udf_double = F.udf(convert, MapType(StringType(), DoubleType()))
convert_udf_bool = F.udf(convert, MapType(StringType(), BooleanType()))

dfs = dfs.withColumn('value_dict_string', convert_udf_str(F.struct(column_list_string)))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('value_dict_int', convert_udf_int(F.struct(column_list_int)))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('value_dict_double', convert_udf_double(F.struct(column_list_double)))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('value_dict_booleean', convert_udf_bool(F.struct(column_list_bool)))

dfs = dfs.withColumn('value_dict', map_concat(dfs['value_dict_string'],dfs['value_dict_int'],dfs['value_dict_double'],dfs['value_dict_booleean']))
```

Error i see is

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1179.withColumn.
> : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'map_concat(`value_dict_string`, `value_dict_int`, `value_dict_double`, `value_dict_booleean`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function map_concat should all be the same type, but it's [map<string,string>, map<string,int>, map<string,double>, map<string,boolean>];;
> 'Project [ADDRESS_ID#994, CAS_ID#995, VERSION#996, RG_ADDRESS#997, IS_VERIFIED#998, GEOFENCE_RADIUS#999, ADDRESS_RECENCY#1000, ADDRESS_SCORE#1001, LAT#1002, LNG#1003, LAT_LNG_ACCURACY#1004, LAT_LNG_CONFIDENCE#1005, map_concat(value_dict_string#1423, value_dict_int#1442, value_dict_double#1461, value_dict_booleean#1480) AS value_dict#1498, value_dict_string#1423, value_dict_int#1442, value_dict_double#1461, value_dict_booleean#1480]

Comment: def convert(s, c = column_list):
...     print(s,c)
...     return {c[0]: s[0], c[1] : s[1], c[2]: s[2], c[3]: s[3], c[4] : s[4], c[5]: s[5] ,c[6]: s[6], c[7] : s[7], c[8]: s[8] ,c[9]: s[9]}
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'column_list' is not defined. could you add the column_list

Comment: column_list is like below:

column_list = ['ADDRESS_ID', 'CAS_ID', 'VERSION','RG_ADDRESS','IS_VERIFIED', 'GEOFENCE_RADIUS', 'ADDRESS_RECENCY', 'ADDRESS_SCORE', 'LAT', 'LNG']

since each column is different type i gave 

column_list_string = ['ADDRESS_ID', 'CAS_ID','RG_ADDRESS']
column_list_int = ['VERSION', 'GEOFENCE_RADIUS', 'ADDRESS_RECENCY', 'ADDRESS_SCORE']
column_list_double = ['LAT', 'LNG']
column_list_bool = ['IS_VERIFIED']

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm trying to convert few columns of a pyspark dataframe into a map but I'm getting a similar error - `data type mismatch: The given values of function map should all be the same type`